# Firefox doesn‘t accept .wav with bootstrap b-form-file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, input

```
 <b-form-file
        @change="onFileChange"
        class="formFile"
        accept="audio/wav|.wav"
        v-model="audioWav"
        :state="Boolean(audioWav)"
        placeholder="Wähle eine Audio .wav Datei aus ziehe sie hier rein..."
        drop-placeholder="Lass sie fallen..."
    ></b-form-file>

onFileChange(event) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      if (file && this.acceptedTypes.indexOf(file.type) === -1) {
          if(file.type !== 'audio/wav') {
            this.makeToast("Falscher Dateityp!","Wähle bitte nur Audiodateien mit der Endung .wav aus.","danger",false)
            event.target.value = null
          } else {
            this.makeToast("Erfolgreich","Auswählen war erfolgreich!","success",false)
          }
      } else {
        this.makeToast("Erfolgreich","Auswählen war erfolgreich!","success",false)
      }
```

This function should check an file, and accept just .wav files for this bootstrap b-form-file, for android on the chrome browser it works well, but for android firefox brwoser and iOS Safari, it doesnt accept .wav files and I dont know exactly why, has someone an idea for that?

I should simply accept the .wav files. For iOS I cant even choose the file, because it is disabled

Comment: Seems like you have a typo here: `accept="audio/wav|.wav"` the `accept` attribute takes **comma-separated** values not `|` separated. Try `accept="audio/wav,.wav"`

Comment: @Kosh , I could solve it now, one of the problems were that, what yo mentions, acutally I had to seperate it by a comma. The solution was, to split the name of the file and check, whats after that point, that worked really well for me.